# Initializing a window in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This is some of the code I have:

```
[window setLevel:kCGScreenSaverWindowLevel];
[window setOpaque:NO];
[window setStyleMask:0];
[window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.0 alpha:0.3]];
[window setAlphaValue:0];

[window setFrame:[window frameRectForContentRect:[[window screen] frame]] display:YES animate:YES];

[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[[window animator] setAlphaValue:1.0];
```

I was just wondering if there was any way to compact it, all of those commands to my window. Any ways to improve it too?

Comment: Off the top of my head: can any of it be done in interface builder?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a number of these properties can be set in IB. I think the meat of the question is do you actually need to create this window programatically, or could you load it from a NIB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a highly readable style, and simple. You might be able to make a loop and run through the list in some fashion, but it's unlikely to actually lower complexity, just shift it around a bit.

Comment: It's just that for example in AppleScript (One of the first things I learnt) you can just do a 'tell' block... like "Tell myWindow" and then list all of the commands. It saves typing out 'window' over and over again

Comment: Yeah, that'd be nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling this code more than once, I would do this:

In the **implementation** file:

```
#import "ThisClass.h"

@interface ThisClass() {}
    - (void)doWindowStuff;

@end

@implementation ThisClass

- (void)doWindowStuff
{
    window.level = kCGScreenSaverWindowLevel;
    [window setOpaque:NO];
    window.styleMask = 0;
    window.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.0 alpha:0.3];
    window.alphaValue = 0;

    [window setFrame:[window frameRectForContentRect:window.screen.frame] display:YES animate:YES];

    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    [window.animator setAlphaValue:1.0];
}

- (void)someOtherMethods
{
    // other code
    [self doWindowStuff];
}
```

---

Note: (from experience) beware interface builder...  setting some things in IB can make code harder to troubleshoot and/or read.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you feel about the use of Objective-C 2.0 properties you can you can:

```
window.level = kCGScreenSaverWindowLevel;
[window setOpaque:NO];
window.styleMask = 0;
window.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:0.0 alpha:0.3];
window.alphaValue = 0;

[window setFrame:[window frameRectForContentRect:window.screen.frame] display:YES animate:YES];

[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
[window.animator setAlphaValue:1.0];
```

I had programmed in C# for many years before taking up Objective-C and I still find the bracket notation hard to read at times. For my own readability I would would also introduce a variable for the new frame.

```
NSRect newFrame = [window frameRectForContentRect:window.screen.frame];
[window setFrame:newFrame display:YES animate:YES];
```